# waitpid returns pid=0 and WIFEXITED=1 how to get pid?

Tags: c, linux, pid, waitpid

Steps:

Fork and start process in a different program group
Stop process with SIGTSTP
Restart process with SIGCONT
Process ends

Problem:
The SIGCHLD handler has:

```
waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED);
```

upon return pid=0 and WIFEXITED=1
so, the process exited, but I can't get the pid?
I need the pid.

From the man page: "if WNOHANG was specified and one or more child(ren) specified by pid exist, but have not yet changed state, then 0 is returned"
But it seems the status has changed to exited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The status is meaningless if the pid returned was 0.  Think about it.  A return of 0 means you have one or more children that have yet to change state.  What would the state of a child that has yet to change state be?  If there were multiple children, which child is the status code referencing?

This is analogous to checking errno on a successful call.  Anything from a previous call can be in errno but it has nothing to do with the most recent successful call because errno is usually not set on success.

Comment: +1 `status` is only modified if the return value is > 0

Comment: So, this helped me look elsewhere for the error. Thanks.

Comment: Also keep in mind that, using WUNTRACED, waitpid() (and wait(), of course) will return if there's a process which has been stopped (by SIGSTOP). In *spite* of the fact that the man page says "WUNTRACED
The status of any child processes specified by pid that are stopped, and whose status has not yet been reported since they stopped, shall also be reported to the requesting process.", the 2.6.32 kernel I tested on will *not* alter the status variable. Your only indication (that I know of) that the return from wait was the result of a SIGSTOP is a return value of -1.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `waitpid` is the PID of the child that was waited for.

Comment: The pid is not zero...<br>From the man page: "if WNOHANG was specified and one or more child(ren) specified by pid exist, but have not yet changed state, then 0 is returned"<br>But it seems the status has changed to exited.

Comment: @donkon: Ah, OK: The parent may receive the signal before the child is reapable. You should perhaps not have WNOHANG in the signal handler in that case.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It is common to have a loop with `waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)` in a signal handler for `SIGCHLD` (e.g. to emulate `SA_NOCLDWAIT` without breaking `waitpid`'s functionality so much). Also, what is the point of `SIGCHLD` if it does not indicate status is immediately available?

Comment: @jilles: You don't have to run `waitpid` in a signal handler. If you run it inside some other multiplexing loop, you may very well want a non-blocking version.